# C# different TPL ActionBlock behavior on windows server 2016 than on windows 10 home

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm using the TPL ActionBlock for a web crawler I'm working on.

It runs fine on my development PC which is windows 10 home, however on my Windows Server DataCenter 2016 if throws an exception when I call.

```
actionBlock.Completion.Wait();
```

The message is

```
One or more errors occurred.
```

With the inner exception being

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
```

The annoying part is even when I have visual studio running on my server in debug mode I can't figure out where the error that's in the exception is being created.

Here is how I'm using the ActionBlock

```
actionBlock = new ActionBlock<URLsToCheckObject>(URLToCheck =>
{
    try
    {
        // get more urls etc here and post below

        actionBlock.Post(new URLsToCheckObject { URLAddress = CleanURL, Host = host });
        if (actionBlock.InputCount == 0) actionBlock.Complete();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        try
        {
            Logger.AddToDebugLog("Block 3 catch...", WebsiteToCrawl);
        }
        catch { }
    }

}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3, CancellationToken = cancellationSource.Token });

actionBlock.Post(new URLsToCheckObject { URLAddress = WebsiteToCrawl.website, Host = host });

try
{
    Logger.AddToDebugLog("Waiting on action block..", WebsiteToCrawl);
    actionBlock.Completion.Wait();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    try
    {
        Logger.AddToDebugLog("Block 4 catch..." + ex.Message, WebsiteToCrawl);
    }
    catch { }

    try
    {
        Logger.AddToDebugLog("Block 4 catch..." + ex.InnerException, WebsiteToCrawl);
    }
    catch { }

    try
    {
        Logger.AddToDebugLog("Block 4 catch...", WebsiteToCrawl);
    }
    catch { }
}
```

What could be causing this difference in when

```
actionBlock.Completion.Wait();
```

Throws an exception on different operating systems?

Comment: If you put an empty `try/catch` inside an empty `try/catch` is it really empty?

Comment: I would expect that you get timeouts on your server, maybe there is some policy that prevents you from accessing some webpages? As a best practice should await the completion of the action block and not use the Wait() method.

Comment: Thanks, why would the try/catch the covers all of the code inside the ActionBlock not catch these errors?